# How to disable TLS in postfix?

Tags: ssl, postfix

How can I disable TLS in postfix? I have problems sending email to a specific host, they said I should disable TLS as I am not using it. Emails are not arriving to indamail.hu ever.

```
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 220 mail13.indamail.hu ESMTP
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: > mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: EHLO server.xxx.hu
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250-mail13.indamail.hu
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250-STARTTLS
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250-PIPELINING
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250-8BITMIME
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250-SIZE 10485760
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: < mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: > mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: MAIL FROM:<info@xxx.hu> SIZE=2365 BODY=8BITMIME
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: > mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: RCPT TO:<ccc@indamail.hu>
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: > mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]: DATA
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: send attr reason = lost connection with mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53] while sending MAIL FROM
Apr  6 16:21:15 server postfix/smtp[12059]: 70B132188649: to=<ccc@indamail.hu>, relay=mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53]:25, delay=163321, delays=163319/0.02/1.4/0.04, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail13.indamail.hu[91.83.45.53] while sending MAIL FROM)
```

main.cf contains

```
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_use_tls = no
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your main.cf for [smtp_tls_security_level](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level) or [smtpd_tls_security_level](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_security_level).

Comment: Added both
smtp_tls_security_level = none
smtpd_tls_security_level = none
but I still see Apr  6 17:14:26 server postfix/smtp[17820]: < mail15.indamail.hu[91.83.45.55]: 250-STARTTLS

Comment: This is the announcement of `mail15.indamail.hu` that it supports connection upgrades with `STARTTLS`. The point is that your MTA doesn't issue `STARTTLS` and thus just uses a plain-text connection.

Comment: Your log says you were disconnected while trying to send mail (i.e. at MAIL FROM:) stage. To get a clearer picture, you will need more information from the recipient mail server (hopefully a sample log entry.) They seem to be interpreting the error as caused by TLS, but may be something else in their smtpd_sender_restrictions, possibly something like DNS reverse PTR?